# error installing packages via conda (python3)

Tags: python, time, conda, miniconda

I am in a conda virtual environment and am getting a `PackagesNotFoundError` error when running

`conda install --name myenv --file my_packages.txt` where my_packages.txt is a text file with a python package name on each line.

but some packages that were giving me an error existed in the conda-forge environment (i had already --append conda-forge to my virtual environment), so I tried some of the failed packages individually, e.g.:

`conda install -c conda-forge time`

as well as all the other options that are listed here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/time
but am still getting the same `PackagesNotFoundError` each time.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

For extra context, the other packages I'm having issues with are: websockets, nest_asyncio, hmac, json, base64, etc.
But the `time` packages is very confusing since it clearly exists in conda-forge (^ link).

I can post the current channels listed via the error output in the comments since StackOverflow isn't letting me post so many links.

I am using:

- conda 22.11.1 (from miniconda)
- MacOS 13.0.1

Thank you.

Comment: if relevant, the current channels in the error output are:

> https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf202003/osx-arm64
> https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf202003/noarch
> https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
> https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
> https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
> https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
> https://conda.anaconda.org/json/osx-arm64
> https://conda.anaconda.org/json/noarch

Comment: Please don't use comments to add info - edit the question.

Comment: Not same package, but duplicate has the answer: Conda doesn't build all packages for **osx-arm64**.